# ImageField not uploading in form, uploads fine in admin panel

Tags: python, django

I have a registration form where users can upload an avatar for their profile, but I cannot get it to work. I've set the media properly:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I have a ImageField in my Profile model as such:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    def is_square_png(self):
        if not self.name.endswith('.png'):
            raise ValidationError("You may only upload .png files!")
        else:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(self)
            if not h == w:
                raise ValidationError("This picture is not square! Your picture must be equally wide as its height.")
            else:
                if not (h + w) >= 1000:
                    raise ValidationError("This picture is too small! The minimum dimensions are 500 by 500 pixels.")
                else:
                    if not (h + w) < 2000:
                        raise ValidationError("This picture is too big! The maximum dimensions are 1000 by 1000 pixels.")
        return self

    def generate_user_folder_avatar(instance, filename):
        return "users/%s/%s.png" % (instance.user, 'avatar')

    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_user_folder_avatar,storage=OverwriteStorage(),validators=[is_square_png],blank=True)

    ...
```

And in my ModelForm, I also include it:

```
class  UserProfileForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'field-input-element'

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('display_name', 'avatar', 'birthday', 'usertype', 'daw', 'usergenre', 'gender')
        widgets = {
            'birthday': AdminDateWidget(),
        }
```

As well as in my views:

```
def RegisterView(request):

    registration_success = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='uf')
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='upf')

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_atr = user_form.save()
            user_atr.set_password(user_atr.password)
            user_atr.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user_atr

            profile.avatar = request.FILES.get('avatar')

            profile.save()
            registration_success = True

            user_atr = authenticate(username=user_form.cleaned_data['username'],
                        password=user_form.cleaned_data['password'],
                        )
            login(request, user_atr)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

        else:
            print (user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm(prefix='uf')
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(prefix='upf')

    return render(request, 'profile/register.html', {'profile_form': profile_form, 'user_form': user_form})
```

No matter what I do, when I submit the form it's as if the field was simply ignored. django does not add the url to the field, nor does it actually upload the file.

I get no errors, nothing! It just simply does not upload and does not add the URL to the model instance.

Comment: Did you print the content of `request.FILES`? Did you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your HTML form?

Comment: Print the content of `request.FILES`? Not sure what you mean by that. But for the latter, yes.

Comment: I meant checking if `request.FILES` contains the uploaded image or if it's empty.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: `if request.method == 'POST': print request.FILES`. If `request.FILES` is an empty dict (`{}`), nothing has been uploaded.

Comment: I do have that in my view, did you not read my code? Edit: Oh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103219/discussion-between-sebastian-olsen-and-lostmyglasses).

Comment: Have you tried removing `profile.avatar = request.FILES.get('avatar')` altogether? Your `ModelForm` should save them image automatically when you hit `profile.save()`?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony That worked, post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image will already be saved by the `ModelForm` so you simply need to remove the line:

```
profile.avatar = request.FILES.get('avatar')
```

and the image will be saved on `profile.save()`